# install run file on hp 625 amd driver

Tags: drivers, ati, hp

Trying to install the [original AMD driver](http://support.amd.com/de-de/download/desktop/legacy?product=Legacy2&os=Linux%20x86_64) my desktop crashes , and my fan is running wild without catalyst.

How should I proceed?

Comment: Welcome to AskUbuntu!  Could you [edit] your question and add a bit more information on the exact model of ATI you're using and the Ubuntu version, ... ;-)

Answer (score 1):

The recommended proprietary graphics driver for your computer is the best graphics driver to install. Open the terminal and type:

```
ubuntu-drivers devices
```

Wait for a minute or two for the command to scan your computer's hardware. The results should identify the recommended proprietary graphics driver for your computer. Install the recommended proprietary graphics driver using `sudo apt-get install recommended-driver` where instead of `recommended-driver` substitute the package name of the recommended proprietary graphics driver. Reboot to enable the newly installed graphics driver.

Comment: What does it mean if you get no results? That there is no recommended proprietary driver and the default open source is best?

Comment: `ubuntu-drivers devices` should show a list of proprietary graphics driver(s) if there are any proprietary graphics drivers available *for your system*. Unfortunately if you have mistakenly installed the wrong graphics driver for your system which you downloaded from the official AMD website or the official NVIDIA website, `ubuntu-drivers devices` will sometimes report that driver as recommended even if it is not working, so you have to uninstall the non-working driver in order to get an accurate recommendation.